# Matrix Inverse in TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, matrix-inverse

I have a problem related to calculating matrix inverse in TensorFlow python interface version 1.1.0 on Linux. What I'm now trying to do is that, I have an input vector as `tensorflow.float64`, say `S` and a value `V`. I augment the vector `S` to be polynomial fashion in the form [image: A=[ 1, S, S^2, S^3 ]] and want to do a regression on `V`. I choose to compute the linear regression myself instead of using the infrastructure from tensorflow, where the regression is conducted as [image: \beta=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T\times V]. The problem occurs at the [image: (A^TA)^{-1}] step, where the inverse multiply the original matrix does not give an identity. However, if I feed the [image: A^TA] as a constant matrix containing the same value as the preprocessed input, the result is really the inverse of itself.

The code below is a runnable version with parameter `control=True` turns on the constant input matrix version where the inverse behaves correctly. Three matrices are output by running the program, the original matrix, the "inverse" by `tf.matrix_inverse`, and the multiplication of the "inverse" with the original matrix aiming to recover an identify. `control=False` gives the same original matrix as `control=True` run, however, the recovered "identity" is not correct with `control=False`. I suspect something wrong with the data flow during preprocessing. However, limited by my experience with TensorFlow, I cannot spot it. Would you mind a help why the `tf.matrix_inverse` does not work as expected?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pprint

def matrixInverse( control=False ):
    '''Compute inverse of a matrix.

Parameters
----------
control : bool
    whether to use control group or not.
    '''
    X = tf.constant( [ [100. , 100., 100., 100.],
         [ 101.75497118 ,  92.84824314 ,  95.09528336 , 103.24955959],
         [ 92.33287485 ,  95.86868862 ,  84.70664178 , 107.9505686 ],
         [ 85.86109085 ,  99.05621029 ,  94.24396596 , 119.60257907] ], dtype=tf.float64 )

    # extract input X
    s = tf.slice( X, [ 2, 0 ], [ 1, 4 ])
    s = tf.squeeze(s)
    s1 = tf.multiply( tf.ones( 4, dtype=tf.float64 ), s )
    s2 = tf.multiply( s, s )
    s3 = tf.multiply( tf.multiply( s, s ), s )

    A = tf.concat( [ tf.ones( 4, dtype=tf.float64 ), s1, s2, s3 ], 0 )
    A = tf.reshape( A, [ 4, 4 ] )

    # filter only the first element in the selected row
    itm = tf.constant( [ True, False, False, False ], dtype=tf.bool )

    A = tf.boolean_mask( tf.transpose(A), itm )

    if control:
        ATA = tf.constant([[  1.00000000e+00,   9.23328748e+01,   8.52535978e+03,   7.87170977e+05],
                     [  9.23328748e+01,   8.52535978e+03,   7.87170977e+05,   7.26817593e+07],
                     [  8.52535978e+03,   7.87170977e+05,   7.26817593e+07,   6.71091579e+09],
                     [  7.87170977e+05,   7.26817593e+07,   6.71091579e+09,   6.19638148e+11]], dtype = tf.float64)
    else:
        ATA = tf.matmul( tf.transpose( A ), A )

    inverseATA = tf.matrix_inverse( ATA )

    sess = tf.Session()
    pprint.pprint( sess.run( [ ATA, inverseATA, tf.matmul( ATA, inverseATA ) ] ) )
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, could not reproduce what i got yesterday. But found that the determinant of A*AT is very close to zero,  so the inverse doesn't exist. The inconsistencies are because of this.

Comment: @vijaym Thanks for the comment. Right, I finally found the same result following your answers. The root cause should be the invertible of the original matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to invert a matrix that is not invertible. So even though it is surprising that copy-pasting the result produces something that looks OK, I would not draw a conclusion as to why a method is better than another at doing something that can't be done.

I would try to reformulate your problem to ensure applying mathematical operations on their domain.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and pointing out the un-invertible matrix. Actually, I want to know with the same input to `matrix_inverse`, why the outputs are different? There is no backward training step in this flow, so in my opinion the computation should be deterministic ignoring the invertibility. Do you have any suggestion figure this problem?

Comment: You are at a singularity, so small differences in the input may result in large differences in the output. It is deterministic, but ill-posed, and I don't think you have a way around that. Remain the fact that copy-pasting producing a seemingly correct output is rather intriguing.

Comment: Btw in case that was not clear: you two `ATA` matrices *are* (slightly) different. Compute their differences to convince yourself.

Comment: Double checked the `ATA` in two cases, you're right that the `control=True` matrix is truncated with greater determinant (10^-4 v.s. 10^-25). Thus probably the observation. My workaround to this problem is to use `py_func` to out-source the regression step to `sklearn` module. Thanks.